# SSL in Asp.Net Core doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, asp.net-core

I created a simple web application from visual studio `Web Application(Net.Core)` template with individual user account authorization.

Then, I enabled SSL in `Project->MyProject Properties...`, copied URL with https to App Url.

Finally, I added:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
});
```

to `Startup`.

And it doesn't work! When I'm starting the application, it just simply turns off after a second, and nothing happens, no error, nothing!

What's wrong with SSL in Asp.Net Core, and how can I enable it correctly?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should use SSL offloading at the reverse proxy server (IIS or nginx), and at Kestrel it should process only HTTP. No documentation right now, https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/enforcing-ssl.html

Comment: @LexLi if it is right, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you using IIS Express to host it in VS? Then you might try to use Jexus Manager to add an HTTPS binding to the web site, https://www.jexusmanager.com

Comment: @LexLi yes, I'm using IIS Express. It already has console, maybe I should use its console?

Comment: Lex Li - IIS Express already does the SSL offloading. And there's no need to use any 3rd party tools, just configure it in the debug settings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For development testing you need to enable SSL first.

Right click the project > Properties > Debug

- Choose "IIS Express" in profile
- Check "Enable SSL"

If your debugging stops after starting (no process ID found), then you have to install the IIS Express self-signed certificate into the certificate store.

You can follow this guide [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/). It's bit older but still applies to Visual Studio 2015. It's due to a bug in Update 3 where IIS Certificate isn't installed in the trusted certificate storage correctly.

Alternatively,

1. hit Win+R, type run "mmc.exe"
2. File > Add Snap-in > Choose "Certificates" > Add > Computer Account > Next > Finish
3. Hit OK
4. Go to "Personal/Certificates". Look for "localhost" Zertificate
5. Drag & Drop the certificate to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
6. Close the MMC. Restart Visual Studio 2015

Now you should be able to debug it.

Comment: Thank you, why is this not enabled by default?

Comment: @Madailei: It should be by now. The answer was related to ASP.NET Core 1.0 which did run on Visual Studio 2015. The newer Templates and on VS 2017.8 should create new projects with SSL already. Also a problem back then was, that there was no tooling for developer certificates. The new .NET Core SDKs install an developer certificate, so it works w/o manual intervention on the certificates to make them trusted in the browser

Comment: Also these days we don't use `[RequireHttps]` attributes and use the middleware instead, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio