# Properly setup IIS Express SSL Cert for Developing .net core mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, asp.net-core, windows-7, iis-express

I am fairly new to .NET Core, and I am working on a new MVC application.  I would like to have SSL enabled such that browsers will not complain about insecure certificates.

I have enabled SSL in the project properties, but the browser still says the certificate is insecure.

Is there a way to configure the certificate either within the appsettings/configuration file, or using the MMC certificates snap in (I am on Windows 7) so that browsers will not complain like this:

[image: Chrome SSL Cert Error]

[image: Chrome Cert Not Secure]

I am in Development, but I am eagerly in search of the proper way to achieve this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39997451/455493

Answer (score 0):

The default certificate generated by IIS Express installer is no longer valid for Chrome, and you have to generate a new one. Also you need to let Windows trust the self-signed certificate.

All steps can be done manually, or via a tool like Jexus Manager. More details can be found in,

https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0